# text input display Nan when I use innerHTML

Tags: javascript, dom-events

For some reason I am not getting the output here:

Javascript

```
var num1 = document.getElementById('number-1').value;
var number1 = parseFloat(num1);
var result = document.getElementById('results');
function generateAddition(){
    result.innerHTML = number1 + number1;
    result.style.backgroundColor = "lightgrey";
}
```

HTML

```
<span id="results"></span>
<input type="number" class="form-control" name="number-1" id="number-1">
<button type="button" onclick="generateAddition()">add</button>
```

Comment: Change to `<input type="number" class="form-control" name="number-1" id="number-1">`

Comment: tried that as well but there was no change in the result

Answer (score 0):

You have to take the value of the input field inside the function call !

```js
var result = document.getElementById('results');
function generateAddition(){
    var num1 = document.getElementById('number-1').value;
    var number1 = parseFloat(num1);
    result.innerHTML = number1 + number1;
    result.style.backgroundColor = "lightgrey";
}
```

```html
<span id="results"></span>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="number-1" id="number-1">
<button type="button" onclick="generateAddition()">add</button>
```

Comment: That worked, but why am I unable to use as a global variable?

Comment: Yes,your code won't work because the input is empty when you load it into your variable, so empty string `""` will be stored in your variable. Hence, you have to take that input and store it into a variable only during the function call (`on Button Click`).

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `generateAddition` is capturing the initial value not the dom object itself. And the initial value is an empty string (`Nan`).
just capture the element itself and keep getting the elements value inside the `generateAddition` function.

```js
var num1 = document.getElementById('number-1');
var result = document.getElementById('results');

function generateAddition() {

    var number1 = parseFloat(num1.value);
    result.innerHTML = number1 + number1;
    result.style.backgroundColor = "lightgrey";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps. Now you can use `num1` as global variable and take/load it's value upon function call!

```js
var num1 = document.getElementById('number-1');
var result = document.getElementById('results');

function generateAddition(){
    var number1 = parseFloat(num1.value);
    result.innerHTML = number1 + number1;
    result.style.backgroundColor = "lightgrey";
}
```

```html
<span id="results"></span>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="number-1" id="number-1">
<button type="button" onclick="generateAddition()">add</button>
```